# Postback happens event after returning false on click of a button

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a ASP.Net button control in my page:

I have JQuery click event for this button:

```
$(':button').click(function (e) {
    if ($('input:checked').length == 0) {
        alert("Please select at least one option.");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The function is called when OK button is called. However the server side event handler is also called. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your form using an `<input type="submit">` ?

The `$(':button')` selector only selects `<button>` and `<input type="button">` elements.

See [api docs here](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/).

If you want to stop the form submitting you are probably better doing:

```
$("form").submit(function () { return false; });
```

This is better because it will also handle a submit triggered by the Enter key for example.